# set phpmyadmin in ubuntu to listen only on localhost port?

Tags: ssh

I can access phpmyadmin by typing in the url: http://234.231.123.123/phpmyadmin.

I wonder where to configure phpmyadmin to only accept http:/:localhost/phpmyadmin so I could use ssh tunneling to connect to it.

Because I dont want other to get to the phpmyadmin page so they could brute force the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restrict who can access the given location (URL path) using your web-server configuration. For example, if you use Apache on Ubuntu, then edit `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` to include `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` directives (only the relevant part included):

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html for more details.

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin config has mechanism for this, assuming you don't want to mess with the webserver configs or have no access to it.

http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#AllowDeny_.28rules.29

Example:

Add this in your phpMyAdmin config file *phpmyadmin/config.inc.php*

This denies all user logins from external connections and allows all user logins from localhost.

```
/* Allow and Deny */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order'] = 'deny,allow';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules'] = array(
'deny % from all',
'allow % from localhost'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming Apache, as your Web server is not identified.

Your Web server would have to be configured to only be bound to the local interface, which could potentially affect any other applications running.  Another solution would be to run an additional instance.

You can also use an ACL in Apache.

If your server is not on a segregated network, you will not be able to fully eliminate the risk.

[Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html)